# how to manually include .config when compiling external kernel module?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel

I'm afraid my question is a bit complex. Appreciate anyone who can help.

Some background:

I have a 3rd party SW package that compile both kernel modules and user space applications.
Unfortunately, this 3rd party is very complex, and doesn't use Kbuild for building kernel modules (I tried without success)

When compiling the kernel modules, I add -I{path to kernel headers}, but I see the .config file is not being parsed in the compilation, which, of course, causes many errors.
I tried to manually add all flags from .config to gcc in command line (using a script to generate the command line) but that was a very very long line and gcc couldn't handle it.

So my question would be: Is there a way to force all these flags to gcc somehow?

Appreciate your ideas :)

**Clarification:**
The 3rd party SW can compile on older kernels (2.6, 2.4) I'm trying to compile it for 3.2
Maybe if someone can explain how the original kernel Makefile manages the .config file, I can mimic that behavior.

Comment: Are you using Make? What does your makefile look like? When compiling a kernel module out-of-tree, my makefile includes something like: 

    make -C $(LINUX_SRC) M=$(KMOD_DIR) modules. Perhaps you should re-evaluate KBuild and try to make it work, otherwise it will be hard to find help.

Comment: Hi, Yes. I'm using make. The make files are given within the 3rd party code, and there are about 100 of them, probably more, spread throughout the code, with all sorts of interconnections between them. I've spent weeks studying them and I still don't understand them entirely. Unfortunately, there are so many configuration flags from various makefiles all around, that using Kbuild just isn't feasable :(

Comment: So the 3rd party SW package "compiles" kernel modules without kbuild.  But then it fails in compilation?  Probably, because it's not using kbuild.  So either the SW works, in which case don't touch, or it doesn't, in which case fix it with kbuild.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should clarify a little more: The SW compiles without Kbuild on kernels 2.4 or 2.6 I'm trying to compile on kernel 3.2 I'll edit my original question. Thanks for pointing this out

Comment: @shayst, even though it would probably end up not working, because you would need more than just the `.config` flags, but anyway to send a huge number of arguments to a program use `xargs` instead of writing in the command line. It's not `gcc` that can't handle it, it's `bash`.

Comment: @Shahbaz, Thanks for the tip. I'll give it a shot. I realize there may be other problems, but given I have no choice, I tackle them one at a time when I encounter them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After digging in the kernel sources, I found  the answer. Here it is in case someone needs it.
There's an automatically generated h file called autoconf.h which contains all the relevant definitions in C pre processor format. Just need to include it manually when compiling the module.

Also in theory, I could use my script to create such a file and include it from the sources.

Hope this helps someone. Now on to the next problem :)

Comment: How will your code find the definition of exported kernel function like kmalloc if you do not use link with the kernel ?

Comment: @VivekS, the code is not actually linked with the kernel. The link is dynamic and at `insmod`-time. Nevertheless, it's important then to turn CONFIG_MODVERSIONS off in the kernel's configuration so that the kernel would load the module, even though during its build some symbols weren't verified (and therefore no kernel version is attached to them).